# mod_alias subdirectory replacement

Tags: regex, apache, redirect, mod-alias

I am using RewriteMatch to redirect all traffic from subdir1 to subdir2, while keeping all other parts of the url the same.  So for instance,

```
http://www.mydomain.com/subdir1/
```

would redirect to

```
http://www.mydomain.com/subdir2/
```

I am using this rule:

```
RedirectMatch 302 /subdir1/.* /subdir2/$1
```

which works for the url

```
http://www.mydomain.com/subdir1/
```

but not for any pages with longer urls.  So it is not matching

```
http://www.mydomain.com/subdir1/index.htm
```

which should be redirected to

```
http://www.mydomain.com/subdir2/index.htm
```

If anyone has any ideas, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this thread help at all? 
http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum92/4097.htm

Answer (score 0):

You would need to round brackets around your .*

```
RedirectMatch 302 /subdir1/(.*) /subdir2/$1
```

Without that $1 is meaningless and is not going to 'know' what to match on.